# Android Cross-compiling ffmpeg

Tags: android, cross-compiling, android-ndk

Is there any option to compile FFMPEG under the ARM (Android NDK) dynamically? (I found only articles about static compiling)
And the second question: when building FFMPEG I can not find files Makefile.am. Can they somehow get it?

Comment: hey.. did you get through this stuff? I am working on exactly same stuff. I followed the answer for this question but m stuck at one point. can u help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I chose this toolchain for the more commonly used 4.4.0 of gcc
when compiling as most arm linux products use it you can change
for your liking, I don't know if it will work with substitutions
so please don't ask. I ran the ./configure command hundreds of
times before I got a succssful build. Therefore I am sharing
what worked maybe it will help you.

Using UBUNTU 32-bit 10.04.03 in VirtuaBox Guest / Host machine is Vista 64

Change `<USERNAME>` to your linux users name

```
mkdir /home/<USERNAME>/applications
cd /home/<USERNAME>/applications
wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r5b-linux-x86.tar.bz2
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.8.7.tar.bz2
tar -xjf android-ndk-r5b-linux-x86.tar.bz2
tar -xjf ffmpeg-0.8.7.tar.bz2
mv ffmpeg-0.8.7 ffmpeg

NDK=/home/<USERNAME>/applications/android-ndk-r5b
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-8 --toolchain=arm-eabi-4.4.0 --install-dir=/home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi

cd ffmpeg
export PATH=/home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi/bin:$PATH
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
./configure \
--target-os=linux \
--cross-prefix=arm-eabi- \
--arch=arm \
--enable-small \
--disable-armvfp \
--prefix=../build/ffmpeg \
--disable-encoders \
--disable-decoders \
--disable-protocols \
--disable-muxers \
--disable-demuxers \
--disable-parsers \
--disable-devices \
--enable-decoder=mp3 \
--enable-decoder=vorbis \
--enable-decoder=alac \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
--enable-decoder=vp8 \
--enable-decoder=flac \
--enable-decoder=pcm_s8 \
--enable-decoder=pcm_u8 \
--enable-decoder=h264 \
--enable-decoder=h263 \
--enable-encoder=adpcm_swf \
--enable-decoder=adpcm_swf \
--enable-encoder=nellymoser \
--enable-decoder=nellymoser \
--enable-encoder=flv \
--enable-decoder=flv \
--enable-encoder=aac \
--enable-decoder=aac \
--enable-decoder=amrnb \
--enable-decoder=amrwb \
--enable-encoder=pcm_s16le \
--enable-decoder=pcm_s16le \
--enable-muxer=amr \
--enable-demuxer=amr \
--enable-muxer=flv \
--enable-demuxer=flv \
--enable-muxer=pcm_s16le \
--enable-demuxer=pcm_s16le \
--enable-muxer=wav \
--enable-demuxer=wav \
--enable-muxer=matroska \
--enable-demuxer=matroska \
--enable-muxer=matroska_audio \
--enable-demuxer=matroska_audio \
--enable-muxer=m4v \
--enable-demuxer=m4v \
--enable-muxer=mov \
--enable-demuxer=mov \
--enable-muxer=h263 \
--enable-demuxer=h263 \
--enable-muxer=h264 \
--enable-demuxer=h264 \
--enable-muxer=webm \
--enable-demuxer=webm \
--enable-muxer=ogg \
--enable-demuxer=ogg \
--enable-muxer=flac \
--enable-demuxer=flac \
--enable-muxer=mpegts \
--enable-demuxer=mpegts \
--enable-muxer=mpegtsraw \
--enable-demuxer=mpegtsraw \
--enable-muxer=aac \
--enable-demuxer=aac \
--enable-parser=aac \
--enable-parser=h263 \
--enable-parser=h264 \
--enable-parser=vp8 \
--enable-parser=mpegvideo \
--enable-parser=mpegaudio \
--enable-parser=mpeg4video \
--enable-parser=flac \
--enable-protocol=rtmps \
--enable-protocol=rtmpt \
--enable-protocol=crypto \
--enable-protocol=rtmpte \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-protocol=pipe \
--enable-protocol=rtp \
--enable-protocol=rtmp \
--enable-protocol=tcp \
--enable-protocol=http \
--enable-protocol=rtmpe \
--enable-protocol=udp \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--extra-cflags='-I/home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi/sysroot/usr/include -fpic -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float' \
--extra-ldflags='-nostdlib /home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.so /home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libm.so -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi/sysroot/usr/lib -L/home/<USERNAME>/applications/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.0' \
--extra-ldflags='-Wl,-dynamic-linker,/system/bin/linker /home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o /home/<USERNAME>/applications/droidtooleabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crtend_android.o' \
--extra-libs=-lgcc
```

Comment: hey.. i followed this thing. It finally gave me a Warning
"arm-eabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail."
How can i tackle it.